# Adding onclick event to a row of Flexigrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I am using the jQuery [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) control in my web application. I just want to add an `onclick` event to every row of the Flexigrid. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('tr').click(function(){  });
```

Comment: in my experience it's sometimes buggy - more consistent (but with overhead) is binding to table cells - $('td')